# Trying to put a timer on colorbox while also placing a cookie & reading it to show only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, cookies, time

Hello and thank you for anyone's help.

I'm trying to do what the title says and I've had success with placing the cookie so the browser reads it and only shows the colorbox popup once per browser session. However, when I try to add a timer to the code it seems to throw the acknowledgement of the cookie out.

Please take a look at a page I've knocked up to show this and explain it all :

http://www.absorbent-spill-kits.co.uk/testing-cookies/cookiepage2.html

If you close the popup, I've written on the page the script and trouble I'm having.

Comment: Please provide relevant code within the question for future readers. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I'll definitely include code on the next post and not just on the example page :) Also, thank you for looking over this.

Comment: @ChrisNaylor Edit your question, and add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it(Partially tested).  You question would probably benefit from more examples.

```
//Check for cookie
if(!$.cookie("colorboxShown")){
    //If no cookie, set a timeout of 3 minutes (1000 milliseconds) * (60 seconds) * (3 minutes)
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "80%", height: "80%", href: "http://www.sitepoint.com" });
    },
    1000*60*3);

    //Your expires will probably work too, this just adds a year to the current date.
    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 1);
    $.cookie('colorboxShown', true, { expires: expires, path: '/' });
}
```

EDIT: For expanded question

From what I understand, you want the timer to popup on whatever page they're visiting.

The first thing you'll want to do is store the current time in the cookie. Like so:

```
    $.cookie('colorboxShown', JSON.stringify({shown: false, started: new Date()}), { expires: expires, path: '/' });
```

This will store both the time started so we can calculate the time left as well as whether or not it has been shown.

Then the first part need so be changed to deal with the new cookie format:

```
var expires = new Date();
expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 1);
var cookie = JSON.parse($.cookie("colorboxShown"))
if(!cookie) {
    cookie = JSON.parse($.cookie('colorboxShown', JSON.stringify({shown: false, started: new Date()}), { expires: expires, path: '/' }));
if(!cookie.shown){
```

More lines are needed both so we don't have to parse the cookie again and so we don't get a TypeError.

Now you need to change the length of the timeout to account for the time in the cookie.

```
var timeStart = cookie.started;
timeStart.setMinutes(timeStart.getMinutes() + 3);
var timeMil = new Date() - timeStart;
```

...

```
},
    timeMil);//1000*60*3);
```

The final piece is to check the cookie before showing the colorbox, and then set the cookie after.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //cookie is already declared. The colorboxShown cookie will be declared so we don't have to check
    cookie = JSON.parse($.cookie("colorboxShown"));
    if(!cookie.shown) {
        $.colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "80%", height: "80%", href: "http://www.sitepoint.com" });
        $.cookie('colorboxShown', JSON.stringify({shown: true, started: cookie.started}), { expires: expires, path: '/' })
    }
},
    timeMil);//1000*60*3);
```

There are drawbacks to this approach. If the user has multiple tabs open of your site, it is possible, though unlikely, that a popup will show in both tabs.

Let me know if you have and questions or if you can't figure out how to get the code to work. I have not tested it, but the logic is sound.

EDIT: Complete Code:

```
var minutes = 1;
$.cookie.json = true;
var expires = new Date();
expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 1);
var cookie = $.cookie("colorboxShown");
if (!cookie) {
    $.cookie('colorboxShown', {
        shown: false,
        started: new Date()
    }, {
        expires: expires,
        path: '/'
    });
    cookie = $.cookie('colorboxShown');
}
console.log(cookie.shown);
if (!cookie.shown) {
    var timeStart = new Date(cookie.started);
    console.log(cookie.started);
    timeStart.setMinutes(timeStart.getMinutes() + minutes);
    var timeMil = timeStart - new Date();
    console.log(timeMil);
    setTimeout(function () {
        //cookie is already declared. The colorboxShown cookie will be declared so we don't have to check
        cookie = $.cookie("colorboxShown");
        if (!cookie.shown) {
            $.colorbox({
                iframe: true,
                width: "80%",
                height: "80%",
                href: "http://www.sitepoint.com"
            });
            $.cookie('colorboxShown', {
                shown: true,
                started: cookie.started
            }, {
                expires: expires,
                path: '/'
            });
        }
    },
    timeMil); //1000*60*3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm getting a 'syntax error'  on the line that just has     }): on it between the 'setTimeout' function and 'var expires'.

The code is as below (I've changed 3 mins to 1 min for testing) : 

    <script>
      //Check for cookie
if(!$.cookie("colorboxShown")){

    setTimeout(function() {
        $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", href: "http://www.sitepoint.com"})},1000*60*1);
    });

    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 1);
    $.cookie('colorboxShown', true, { expires: expires, path: '/' });
}
    </script>

Comment: I've setup another page with the code you provided to test it for a 1 minute popup, but it's not popping up or placing the cookie (maybe because of this syntax error?) http://www.absorbent-spill-kits.co.uk/testing-cookies/cookiepage4.html

Comment: It's because I have bad formatting. Definitely the syntax error. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you so much this is almost there now. So it has the timer and places the cookie so it doesn't keep popping up every x minutes - Fantastic. However if I move to a second page on the site the box doesn't popup (I'm assuming because the first page placed the cookie and the second page says 'if there is a cookie then don't start the timer.') So how would this now be adapted so the timer continues over several pages in the domain until it's end time is reached? Obviously we still need it to not show if this cookie is present to prevent several popups, but perhaps check overall cookie time?

Comment: I've added the code to the link again explained a little further : http://www.absorbent-spill-kits.co.uk/testing-cookies/cookiepage4.html

Thankyou once again for your outstanding help on this.

Comment: I've added the changes. Let me know if you have any questions or problems putting the snippets together.

Comment: Hello again. I know it's been ages since I was on this, but I'm back and have tried the new code you kindly provided. There seems to be an error on the code at the }, line before the timeMil);//1000*60*1);  bit   .I've uploaded a page again that shows the place of the error : http://www.absorbent-spill-kits.co.uk/testing-cookies/cookiepage5.html  Please could you have a look at the code I'm using on the page and see if something is jumping out at you that I've made a mistake on or any oversights. Thanks again for all of your help to date. Chris.

Comment: Let me know if the complete solution at the bottom of the answer works for you.

Comment: Once again thank you so much for your assistance and I think we're nearly there. I've uploaded another page (page 6 this time) http://www.absorbent-spill-kits.co.uk/testing-cookies/cookiepage6.html This page explains the current situation, but it seems to be placing the cookie successfully, but resetting the timer back to 1 minute when a new page is viewed, instead of checking the cookie and carrying on the timer...  Was I meant to leave the scripting it an the top before the edited script above beginning with 'var minutes = 1' ?  Also if I close the page and reopen, the timer starts up again.

Comment: Just remove any cookie code except for that last snippet starting with `var minutes = 1`. Change the value of `minutes` to the desired delay. Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjuzeygk/)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. This is working and I've implemented it onto the website and it's working well. I've been asked if I could change the expiry on the cookie to be around a week or two rather than a whole year. Just as a final look at the code, how would I change this expiry? Is it on the line... expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 1);  or on the line a little lower that states.... expires: expires, path: '/'  Thank you once again and if there's any way for me to +1 your profile or somethine, please let me know.

Comment: It is on that line. You'll do `expires.setDate(expires.getDate() + 7)`. If this answer solved, click the check-mark to the top-left of the answer to mark it as an answer. If you think this was a valuable answer, press the up-vote triangle in the same corner. That's the equivalent of +1ing my profile.